# Having problems with css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to add a section below navbar. My problem is that if I don't add `position:fixed; top: 50px` (which is the height of the navbar) then the top of my section is getting covered by navbar.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #f5f6f7;
  color: #1b1b32;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
}


/* NAVBAR */

header {
  height: 51px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f6f8f9;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #fa6980;
  font-size: 13;
}

nav {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

nav>ul>li {
  color: #343638;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
}


/* WORLD NEWS SECTION FLEXBOX */

.world-news {
  display: flex;
  height: 590px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex1 {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url(./world\ news/image.png);
  height: 590px;
  padding-top: 15%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 590px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="logo" class="bold">LOGO</h1>
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="bold">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a class="bold">DISCOVERY</a></li>
      <li><a class="bold">PHOTOS</a></li>
      <li><a class="bold">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt='profile pic sample' id='profile-pic' />
</header>

<section class="flex-box world-news">
  <div class="flex1">
    <div class="try">
      <h2 class="bold">WORLD NEWS</h2>
      <hr>
      <p class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in eam odio amet, vix id nullam detracto vidit.</p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex2">
    <form>
      <label for="date" class="bold">Select a date</label>
      <input name='date' type="date" placeholder="Select...">
      <label for="keywords" class="bold">Enter the first keywords</label>
      <input name="keywords">
      <button class="bold">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: " Please tell me what am I doing wrong" nothing, this is how `position: fixed` is supposed to work. If you don't want this behavior consider using `position: relative`

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your navbar has `position: fixed` it's always going to be at the top and will cover everything underneath it. What I suggest you do is wrap everything else in the page in a `<main>` element and give that main element 50px of padding. Like this...

```
<header>
  Header content here
</header>
<main>
  <section>some content</section>
  <section>some content</section>
</main>
```

And then in your css...

```
main {padding-top: 50px}
```

Comment: Good solution. You should copy the snippet demo down and revise it to demonstrate.